# Reading multiple images in keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, keras

I tried to read multiple images in keras(theano), like this

```
  import numpy as np

  import os, sys

  import cv2

  my_path='data/train'

  dirs = os.listdir(my_path)

  numpy_int_array=np.array(dirs)

  for i in numpy_int_array:

        input_im=cv2.imread(numpy_int_array[i],1)

        print input_im.shape
```

I am getting below error,

**IndexError**: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), 
numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Please help me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: why do you convert `dirs` to `np.array`?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting to `np.array` too soon:

```
for im_name in os.listdir(my_path):  # no need to convert to np.array yet...
    input_im=cv2.imread(im_name, 1)  # now it's np.array
    print input_im.shape
```

Python's [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of file *names* (strings) and not integers.